# EntityFramework Core 2.0 skip loading column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm having some files saved into a MSSQL database using EF core with a structure like

```
public class UploadedFile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
```

I want to be able to load the list of "UploadedFiles" from database without actually reading the Content column from the database. So I can't really use

`await _context.UploadedFiles.ToListAsync();`

I believe I can use something like bellow with a stored procedure.

`_context.Set<UploadedFiles>().FromSql("dbo.spGetUploadedFiles")`

But, is there any other way that would not involve using a stored procedure? I can't un-map the column in the model as I need it for insert/read individual items.
Thank you.

Comment: Does reading a projection violate any of your requirements? e.g. _context.UploadedFiles.Select(uf => new { uf.Id, uf.Source })?

Comment: @Eric  I think you are right, I can do with projection. I will try to actually profile the query, please post it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a projection:

```
var results = _context.UploadedFiles.Select(uf => new { uf.Id, uf.Source });
```

Comment: I ended up with _context.UploadedFiles.Select(up => new UploadedFile() { Id = up.Id, Source = up.Source }).ToListAsync(); as I wanted to result into a UploadedFile object.

Answer (score 3):

You can basically use `.Select({..)` to specify which columns you want to return:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
}

var data = _context.UploadedFiles
    .Select(p => new MyItem
    {
        Id = p.Id,
        Source = p.Source
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

This way you tell EF to generate the select only for those columns and nothing more. You can also select an anonymous object like `.Select(p => new { ... })` if you feel like so.

I strongly recommend using strong types.

Comment: Thanks Cristian, I also preffer strongly typed data (and needed here) but Eric answer was first